# ORA-00904: "SS"."SAMPLE_SIZE": invalid identifier

Tags: ora-00904

I am trying to create a table using this set of 47 commands and keep getting an error "00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" in the row 24 with ss.sample_size value:

```
1 CREATE TABLE BN_NAM_CPB_SAMPLES AS
2 SELECT XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS,
3        XXX_COUNTRY,
4        CLIENT_CATEGORY,
5        RULE_1,
6        POPULATION_TYPE,
7        SAMPLE_SIZE,
8        PARTITION_ROWNUM,
9        ID,
10       UNIQUE_ID,
11       ACCT_INTRL_ID,
12       RANDOM_VALUE
13 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
14                  OVER (
15                     PARTITION BY A.XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS,16
16                                  A.XXX_COUNTRY,
17                                  A.CLIENT_CATEGORY,
18                                  A.RULE_1,
19                                  A.CPB_CUST_SGMT,
20                                  A.POPULATION_TYPE
21                     ORDER BY A.RANDOM_VALUE)
22                     AS PARTITION_ROWNUM,
23                  A.*,
24                  ss.sample_size
25             FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS ID,
26                          A.*,
27                          DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 1) AS RANDOM_VALUE
28                     FROM (SELECT XXX_COUNTRY,
29                                  CLIENT_CATEGORY,
30                                  XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS,
31                                  UNIQUE_ID,
32                                  ACCT_INTRL_ID,
33                                  RULE_1,
34                                  CPB_CUST_SGMT,
35                                  POPULATION_TYPE
36                             FROM BN_CPB_POP_FOR_SAMPLING
37                           ) A) A
38                  INNER JOIN
39                  BN_CPB_SAMPLE_SIZES SS
40                    ON     A.XXX_COUNTRY = SS.XXX_COUNTRY
41                     AND A.CLIENT_CATEGORY = SS.CLIENT_CATEGORY
42                     AND A.POPULATION_TYPE = SS.POPULATION_TYPE
43                     AND A.XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS = SS.XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS
44                     AND A.RULE_1 = SS.RULE_1
45                     AND A.CPB_CUST_SGMT = SS.CPB_CUST_SGMT
46                     ) B
47    WHERE B.PARTITION_ROWNUM <= B.SAMPLE_SIZE;
```

BN_CPB_SAMPLE_SIZES table was created in a previous step using the following query:

```
48 CREATE TABLE BN_CPB_SAMPLE_SIZES AS
49 SELECT                     XXX_LINE_OF_BUSINESS,
50                            XXX_COUNTRY,
51                            CLIENT_CATEGORY,
52                            CPB_CUST_SGMT,
53                            RULE_1,
54                            POPULATION_TYPE,
55                            UNIQUE_ID,
56                            ACCT_INTRL_ID
57                         FROM BN_CPB_POP_FOR_SAMPLING;
```

Comment: It has been resolved using a simple solution:

Comment: CREATE TABLE BN_CPB_SAMPLE_SIZES (        
    xxx_LINE_OF_BUSINESS VARCHAR(200),
    xxx_COUNTRY VARCHAR(200),
    CLIENT_CATEGORY VARCHAR(200)  ,
    CPB_CUST_SGMT VARCHAR(200),
    RULE_1 VARCHAR(200),
    POPULATION_TYPE VARCHAR(200),
    POPULATION_SIZE NUMBER, 
    SAMPLE_SIZE NUMBER
    );

Comment: SAMPLE_SIZE was added as a separate column in a table instead of creating a table with SELECT ... FROM VIEW statement. (lines 48 - 57 above)